# Mapping different column name in relations on MANY_MANY

Tags: many-to-many, yii

In Yii is there a restriction on the table column names for joins?

You see, I have two tables plus a join table for the MANY_MANY relationship but the column names are unfortunately different in all of them, I am unable to change the column names to match due to restrictions.

So in Table1 I have a column table1_id which is the PK

In Table2 I have a column Table2ID which is the PK

Then in the Join table, Table3, I have 2 columns Table1ID and Table2ID

Note that Table1's PK is table1_id but the join table uses Table1ID

I need the many to many relationship to work with the different names. So I have this relations function in Table1 AR Class

```
// Table 1 column name is table1_id, but join table has it as Table1ID
class Table1 extends CActiveRecord {
    public function relations() {
        return array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Table2', 'Table3(Table1ID, Table2ID)');
    }
}

class Table2 extends CActiveRecord {
    public function relations() {
        return array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Table1', 'Table3(Table2ID, Table1ID)');
    }
}
```

This keep **throwing an error**: `Invalid column name 'table1_id'`

As I said earlier it is not possible to change the column names in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'm not sure how you are calling the relation from this example. You need to name the relation, I think, like so (`table1Relation`):

```
class Table2 extends CActiveRecord {
  public function relations() {
    return array('table1Relation'=>array(
      self::MANY_MANY, 'Table1', 'Table3(Table2ID, Table1ID)')
    );
  }
}
```

Then you call `$myTable2Model->table1Relation` to get the relation. But perhaps you forgot to type that part of the code and are already doing this...

**Is the error `Invalid column name 'table1_id'` on `Table2`, or `Table1`?** The relation might be looking for the primary key in the wrong table. If you could show the *entire* error message that might help a lot, actually, in solving this.

**You might just need to switch the order of your relation table declaration** (i.e. `Table1ID,Table2ID` instead of `Table2ID, Table1ID`). Try this:

```
class Table2 extends CActiveRecord {
  public function relations() {
    return array('table1Relation'=>array(
      self::MANY_MANY, 'Table1', 'Table3(Table1ID,Table2ID)')
    );
  }
}
```

I hope that helps, a little. :) Good luck!